# PHP session issue sometimes doesn't get saved

Tags: php, session

I'm troubled with some PHP session issues.

I have a main page, where i start the session, and some links to a second page. I want to keep track of the pages (breadcrumbs), so i store these in the session.
When i test, this works for some, and doesn't for others... i don't see the problem.

Page 1: (index.php)

```html
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['kruimels'])){
    $_SESSION['kruimels']["home"]="index.php");
}else{
    unset($_SESSION['kruimels']);
    array_push($_SESSION['kruimels']["home"]="index.php");
}

?>

<a href='sub.php?id=1'>item1</a>
<a href='sub.php?id=2'>item2</a>
<a href='sub.php?id=3'>item3</a>
<a href='sub.php?id=4'>item4</a>
```

Second page: (sub.php)

```html
<?php

session_start();

/* I get the name of the page by querying the DB...*/

if (isset($_SESSION['kruimels'])){
    $_SESSION['kruimels'][$nameOfPage]="sub.php?id=".$_GET['id'];
}

?>

<?php
foreach ($_SESSION['kruimels'] as $naam => $path) {
   echo "<li><a href='$path'>$naam</a></li>";
}
                    
?>
```

The strange thing is, somethimes it gets saved, sometimes it doesn't...
i don't see the problem...

Help?
Greetings,
Martijn

Answer (score 0):

you have no need to start a session for this just use basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); this function of php. This will give you the name of your current file. 
After this, you got your file name and now explode this with (.) And echo wherever you want to show
And than Try below code

```
 $pagename = explode('.', basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
                echo $pagename[0];
```

Comment: I want to keep track of all visited links. 
On the sub page are also links to the subpage with a different id. 

index->sub->sub->... like breadcrumbs. 

But i sometimes (not always) get index-> sub in stead of index->sub->sub